Observer pattern: hide update method from classes which are not the Publisher
Context
I am writing a simple simulation library which includes Entity and Event classes.
I decided to implement the Observer pattern so that as soon as an Event is simulated (Publisher), it can notify any Entity subscribed to it (Observer).
public class Event
{
    //declarations
    List<Entity> observers;
    
    public void simulate()
    {
        //do stuff
        notify();
    }

    private void notifyObservers()
    {
        observers.ForEach(o => o.update());
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    //declarations

    public void update()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

Entity now exposes the update() method, which is intended to be called by an Event (or at least a class which Entity is subscribed to).
My worry is that a naive user of my library may  define an Entity and call update() within their code, with the risk of putting the simulation into an invalid state.
Question
How can I "hide" the update() method from the Observer's public interface, preventing its misuse?
Possible solutions I could think of:

define update() as internal (I've heard it's bad practice, but this could be a good use case)
Make an EntityFacade class which wraps an Entity, not exposing the method. This way users of the library would have one more hoop to jump through (wrapee stll needs to be accessible)
ignore the problem altogether, assume users won't call the method despite it showing in the intellisense


Use different interfaces for each case and only give the appropriate interface to users, not the class itself. .NET's Channel class (essentially an async queue that may interest you) goes even farther, forcing users to use either a ChannelReader or a ChannelWriter to read or publish. Users don't even need access to the Channel itself

Side note: You might want to check the Rx library.

In your case, it is correct to use the interface segregation principle.

Since you have a user who will interact with the entity, then provide one interface (let's say he can view the state of the entity, then let him use the State interface - which does not contain the update() method).
Since the event uses the update() method, provide it with another interface, say Updateable.
Implement both interfaces in your Entity class (class Entity : State, Updateable).

P.S. In such a solution, neither the user nor the Event will use the Entity class directly, they will both use their interfaces, with exactly the methods that you define for a particular consumer.
